# Tool for determining version of Win32 APIs used by C++ code?

Tags: c++, winapi, api, version

I'm modifying a large C++ project whose first release was Windows 7-only to work on Vista and XP.

The main work will be to change the W7 API calls to use GetProcAddress at runtime (to avoid static linking with methods that are not available on the other platforms), and so I'm wondering if there are any tools that can help identify which calls need to be changed -- hopefully by examining the C++ code itself.

Failing that, would it be best to try building the project against an older Windows SDK? -- for example: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=6510

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#define WINVER 0x501
```

Now everything that is newer than Windows XP will cause a compilation error.

Replace everything that causes an error until none remain.

If you have some `sed`-fu, you can probably write a filter that directly finds all `#if WINVER > 0x501` blocks in the windows headers, but for me, this is a bit out of my scope :-)

Comment: So that got me on the right track; WINVER is deprecated - the new official way to do things is NTDDI_VERSION, as described in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745.aspx -- but yeah, your method will work (seems so obvious now) -- thanks!

Comment: When was WINVER deprecated in favor of NTDDI_VERSION? If that was a Vista/7 change, you may have to port it back as well. :P

Comment: @peachykeen: that was my impression, anyway, since defining WINVER didn't seem to make any difference to the SDK includes. (I got no errors from the Win7 calls.)

Comment: You might try `_WIN32_WINNT` in addition or instead of `WINVER` too. Though on my system, if you define one, the other gets set to the same value. But they do exist both (not sure which one is the more recent).

Comment: @Damon, `NTDDI_VERSION` now seems to be the way to go: among other things, it ensures consistency within the older definitions -- e.g. will error out if `_WIN32_WINNT` or `WINVER` are set to something different.

Answer (score 2):

I would open your binaries using the depends.exe tool (either from your VS install or from [here](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)) under WinXP and Vista to see which functions can't be statically linked under these OSes.  These would be the functions which your binary is using, but which are missing in older releases of the OS.  You'll have to deal with them somehow: either implement them by yourself, replace them with something else or disable some of the functionality of your app.

Comment: Thanks -- I thought about that, but I really wanted source-level info.